# Add dynamic value in url retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, illegalargumentexception

I have this below URL

[URL TO CALL](https://www.ex.com/api/storage/presigned-url?bucketName=files&key=payment-receipt/4155E816-1426-42CD-B788-83510D81D977.jpg&httpVerb=2&contentType=image/jpeg)

In the interface I have as

```
@GET("storage/presigned-url?bucketName=files&key=payment-receipt/{fileName}&httpVerb=2&contentType=image/jpeg")
suspend fun fileUploadPathCheque(@Path("fileName") name: String): Response<String>
```

I want to replace the file name with some value

I am calling the function as

```
Api.fileUploadPathCheque(UUID.randomUUID().toString().plus(".jpg"))
```

I get the following exception

```
ava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL query string "bucketName=files&key=payment-receipt/{fileName}&httpVerb=2&contentType=image/jpeg" must not have replace block. For dynamic query parameters use @Query.
```

What shoudl be correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is self-explanatory, You need to use a query parameter for `key`. Something like

```
@GET("storage/presigned-url?bucketName=files&httpVerb=2&contentType=image/jpeg")
suspend fun fileUploadPathCheque(@Query("key") name: String): Response<String>`
```

and then call it appending `payment-receipt/` to your passing parameter:

```
Api.fileUploadPathCheque("payment-receipt/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString().plus(".jpg"))
```

This should work for you.